# Typescript: use a subset of string as [key: subset]

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Is there any way to indicate Typescript compiler that I want to use as key any string but certain value (subset of string). To get a type like this working:

```
{ category: string; [key: Exclude<string, 'category'>]: number }
```

In this case I get :

**TS1336 An index signature parameter type cannot be a type alias. Consider using [key: string] : number instead**.

Comment: You don't know up front the set of allowed strings? You want  to all allow `x` as a key but disallow `fooooocategory` ? Whats the use case?

Comment: not quite sure I understand what you are after, but maybe you are looking for string enums?

Comment: I want a type definition that ensures the item for 'category' key will be an string, and allow any other string to be key for a number item

Answer (score 0):

You need to use mapped types in order to achieve that, but also `Exclude` will not work with `string` type, it will work with union type only, and string is not an union. The result of `Exclude<string, 'anything'>` will be just `string` below a proof.

```
type StillOnlyString = Exclude<string, 'anything'>
```

In order to achieve excluding we need to provide a type variable which will be an union of keys we will have in the object. Consider:

```
type WithCategory<Keys extends string> = {category : string} & {
  [K in Exclude<Keys,'category'>]: number
}

const x: WithCategory<'other'> = {
  category: 'str',
  other: 1
}
```

Its maybe little bit verbose, but we are ensuring that `category` field is always string and any other will be an `number`.

Comment: This will not solve the typing problem, as the rest of keys used are not defined. I need to enforce category to be string but allow any other string key to contain a number. The rest of the keys may be [other, other1, other2, other3, ...], but are not statically defined.

Comment: Why not nest this structure? Like {category: string, data:Record<string,number} ?

Comment: It would solve the problem for sure. But I'm not managing the resource where I get the data from. I was just trying to make this typing so people reading the code could easily understand there is an string waiting for them in the category key, and all others keys from the object stores numbers. After digging a lot into typescript docs, I think there is not a solution for this. Thanks for your answers!